# use absolute link in ajax

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, absolute

I try to use absolute link but I can not get the file absolute link.

```
<!-- script src="jquery.min.js"></script -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

//-----------
// var fileurl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js";
```

it work when I used this link https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js for absolute link, but it not work when I use my link.

```
 var fileurl = "http://mintnet.net/cas242/abc/images/brown-Rice.jpg";


var listname = [];   

 $.ajax({
    url : fileurl, 
    success: function (data) {
          alert("the file is found");
     //  callback(data);
    },
     error: function () {  
          alert("the file doesn't exist");

    }
});

</script>
```

I alert out if get file success or not.

Comment: it's worth it to learn about the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), as this is likely why you can't access the desired file

Comment: Thank! I took the file to same origin domain and it work. Do anyway that I can make it work in local with a local file on my computer? like get data from a file on computer.